# Getting string array using angular $resource TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, typescript, angular-resource

by making request to WebAPI I expect to receive string array with several values (units of measurement in this case) ["KGM", "MTR"]

Unfortunately in response I'm receiving array of resources and within array of chars

```
[0] Resource
    [0]: "K"
    [1]: "G"
    [2]: "M"
[1] Resource
    [0]: "M"
    [1]: "T"
    [2]: "R"
```

img: http://snag.gy/dDerV.jpg

Here is request which I do and how I'm carry the response

```
var provider = this.resource(WebAPIDataUrl, {}
, {
    GetData: {
        method: 'GET'
        , params: {
            action: "GetData"
        }, isArray: true
        , headers: {
            'Token': this.window.sessionStorage.getItem("Token")
        }
    }
});
var _success = function (resource: string[]) {
    _unitsOfMeasurements = Object.keys(resource);
};
var _error = function () {
};

provider.GetData(_success, _error);
```

I have also created a hook by using `transformResponse` to be sure that incoming data is in proper format and it's ok:

```
transformResponse: function(data, headers){
    return data;
}
data == '["KGM", "MTR"]'
```

So question is how should treat response to have nice string[] ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the raw response with us?

If you need to work with the response you have, you can obtain the strings using the `array.prototype.join` method.

```
response = [
    ['K','G','M'],
    ['M','T','R']
];

for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var string = response[i].join('');
    console.log(string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$resource only works with objects or arrays of objects, not strings.

You could wrap the strings in objects or as a suggestion in this [thread](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2664) regarding this issue says, if you want an array of strings you could use $http instead.